# Metal compute values isnt the same as the CPU values

Tags: objective-c, metal

I'm trying to implement a length of a vector of 3DPoints and when I compare the values retrieved by the GPU with the CPU they aren't entirely the same, usually having a large number of differences.
I initially used packed_float3 and it present a bit more differences, so I started to use float3 and improved a little bit but there are still differences that I would like to fix.

The values don't differ a lot, on average they differ by -0.00000000048358334004, but when I run operations like summing and subtracting two arrays the difference doesn't occur and I would like that that it would happen the same.

Here is a part of the Code

main.m

```
- (void) lenght_function:(NSArray*) array {
    _buffer[0] = [_mDevice newBufferWithLength:_sp_size_alloc options:MTLResourceStorageModeShared];
    _buffer[1] = [_mDevice newBufferWithLength:_sp_size_alloc options:MTLResourceStorageModeShared];
    float3 *datapt = [_buffer[0] contents];

    for (unsigned long index = 0 ; index< _sp_lenght ; index++) {
        datapt[index].x = (float)[array[index] getX];
        datapt[index].y = (float)[array[index] getY];
        datapt[index].z = (float)[array[index] getZ];


    }
    commandBuffer = [_mCommandQueue commandBuffer];
    assert(commandBuffer != nil);
    
    id<MTLComputeCommandEncoder> computeEncoder = [commandBuffer computeCommandEncoder];
    assert(computeEncoder != nil);

    [computeEncoder setComputePipelineState:_mLenghtFunctionPSO];
    
    [computeEncoder setBuffer:_buffer[0] offset:0 atIndex:0];
    [computeEncoder setBuffer:_buffer[1] offset:0 atIndex:1];
    //[array1 makeData];
    
    MTLSize gridSize = MTLSizeMake(_sp_lenght, 1, 1);
   
    NSUInteger threadGroupSize = _mLenghtFunctionPSO.maxTotalThreadsPerThreadgroup;
    if(threadGroupSize > _sp_lenght){
        threadGroupSize = _sp_lenght;
    }
    
    MTLSize threadgroupsize = MTLSizeMake(threadGroupSize, 1, 1);
    
    [computeEncoder dispatchThreads:gridSize threadsPerThreadgroup:threadgroupsize];
    [computeEncoder endEncoding];
    [commandBuffer commit];
    [commandBuffer waitUntilCompleted];
    float3 *arr1 = _buffer[0].contents;
    float* result = _buffer[1].contents;
    unsigned long counter = 0;
    for (unsigned long index = 0; index < _sp_lenght; index++)
    {
        if (result[index] != sqrtf(arr1[index].x*arr1[index].x + arr1[index].y*arr1[index].y + arr1[index].z*arr1[index].z)){
            counter++;;
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"ERROR counter %lu\n",counter);

}
```

kernel.metal

```
kernel void lenght(const device float3 *arr1,
                         device float *result,
                         uint index[[thread_position_in_grid]]){
    
    result[index] = precise::sqrt(precise::pow(arr1[index].x,2) + precise::pow(arr1[index].y,2) + precise::pow(arr1[index].z,2));

}
```

Comment: Hi. It would be helpful to see the values you are getting and the values you are expecting. How much are they off?

Comment: thank you for your response, I'm also new to StackOverflow and I didn't specify enough the problem so I updated the description to help better understand the problem I'm having.

Comment: Try disabling fastmath for Metal shader compilation and compare again.

Answer (score 0):

32-bit precision is only about 7 decimal places and the difference you show is around 9-10 decimal places. So what you show is actually a bit better than one can expect a 32-bit float for precision. It sounds like you want 64-bit double precision, but that is not a built-in Metal datatype.

It may help if you multiply the values by say 100 or 1000 to move the decimal place up, then after your values have been added divide by that number.

Another possibility is to normalize your values first, so they are all in a range of say 0 to 1. Then you might even be able to use half precision.

Comment: thanks for the answer but the thing I can't understand is why do operations like adding and sub don't present any difference and this "function" does.

Comment: The GPU and CPU are very different devices. You just can't count on more than 7 or 8 decimals on anything with a 32-bit float, and is not surprising to me that the GPU is slightly less accurate than the CPU. I think the GPU fundamentally works on FP16, so perhaps it is internally representing the value with two FP16 values.

Comment: I think this premise is wrong. The GPU isn't "less accurate". IEEE-754 is a standard and float operations are defined exactly and the same float operations will yield the same result on basically any modern device that deals with floats. What can happen is compiler can introduce fastmath optimizations that behave differently.

Comment: Refer to a chapter from Physically based rendering book about floating points or this article: https://ciechanow.ski/exposing-floating-point/

Comment: thank you for the clearing, I was using the precise module from metal to have the most  precise data but I still couldn't achieve it

Comment: That makes sense thanks for the explanation. Still, the difference is beyond 32-bit float precision. Is there a reason why the data cannot be normalized?